# C code compiles under Debian-buster but not Debian-bullseye under Docker

Tags: docker, g++, debian, debian-buster

I got a g++ compile error when trying to upgrade from Docker image php:7.2-apache to php:7.4-apache. The base image of php:7.2-apache is debian:buster-slim, and the base image of 7.4-apache is debian:bullseye-slim.

I then recreated the problem between debian:buster-slim and debian:bullseye-slim.

Here's a dockerfile that works:

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    openssh-client \ 
    git \
    nano \
    cron \
    ffmpeg \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmariadb-dev-compat \
    libpng-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libgd-dev \
    g++


WORKDIR "/test"
RUN printf "#include <stdio.h>\n#include <mysql.h>\n#include <jpeglib.h>\nusing namespace std;\nint main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {\nMYSQL mysql;\nmysql_init(&mysql);\nstruct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;\n}" > main.cpp
RUN g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -ljpeg main.cpp -o test
```

Here's a dockerfile that doesn't work:

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    openssh-client \
    git \
    nano \
    cron \
    ffmpeg \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmariadb-dev-compat \
    libpng-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libgd-dev \
    g++

WORKDIR "/test"
RUN printf "#include <stdio.h>\n#include <mysql.h>\n#include <jpeglib.h>\nusing namespace std;\nint main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {\nMYSQL mysql;\nmysql_init(&mysql);\nstruct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;\n}" > main.cpp
RUN g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -ljpeg main.cpp -o test
```

The errors I get include:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `mysql_init'
```

(There's a similar error for the jpeg library if I remove mysql from the dockerfile.)

I believe the problem is that it can't link the mysqlclient and jpeg libraries.

Anyone know the root cause and how to fix? Thanks!

NOTE: I edited the question so that the dockerfiles are self-contained with a "mini" C program (RUN printf...). The image can be built by anyone using:

```
docker build . -t myimage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do reproduce the failed build (W11, Docker Desktop 4.21.1 (114176), Docker 24.0.2):

```
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -ljpeg main.cpp -o test                                                                                 0.5s
------
 > [5/5] RUN g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -ljpeg main.cpp -o test:
0.446 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cclUFOxL.o: in function `main':
0.446 main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `mysql_init'
0.448 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
------
Dockerfile:22
--------------------
  20 |     WORKDIR "/test"
  21 |     RUN printf "#include <stdio.h>\n#include <mysql.h>\n#include <jpeglib.h>\nusing namespace std;\nint main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {\nMYSQL mysql;\nmysql_init(&mysql);\nstruct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;\n}" > main.cpp
  22 | >>> RUN g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -ljpeg main.cpp -o test
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -ljpeg main.cpp -o test" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

But this Dockerfile worked:

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    openssh-client \
    git \
    nano \
    cron \
    ffmpeg \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmariadb-dev-compat \
    libpng-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libgd-dev \
    g++

WORKDIR "/test"
RUN printf "#include <stdio.h>\n#include <mysql.h>\n#include <jpeglib.h>\nusing namespace std;\nint main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {\nMYSQL mysql;\nmysql_init(&mysql);\nstruct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;\n}" > main.cpp
RUN g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -ljpeg -o test
```

Meaning not:

```
RUN g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -ljpeg main.cpp -o test
```

But instead:

```
RUN g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -ljpeg -o test
```

The source file `main.cpp` is placed before the `-l` options.

And note that if you were compiling multiple files, they should all come before the `-l` options.
For example: `g++ -std=c++11 file1.cpp file2.cpp -I/usr/include/mysql -lmysqlclient -ljpeg -o test`.

---

The [buster-slim](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/5c2097f19aac78c4d4a4236c1038d68d2ee2a43a/repos/debian/local/buster-slim.md) image includes a `gcc-8-base:amd64=8.3.0-6`.

The [bullseye-slim](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/5c2097f19aac78c4d4a4236c1038d68d2ee2a43a/repos/debian/local/bullseye-slim.md) image includes a `gcc-10-base:amd64=10.2.1-6`.

The [GCC 10 release](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html) included several linker changes.

> Most `--param` values can now be specified at translation unit granularity. This includes all parameters controlling the inliner and other inter-procedural optimizations.
> Unlike earlier releases, GCC 10 will ignore parameters controlling optimizations specified at link-time and apply parameters specified at compile-time in the same manner as done for optimization flags.

And the current [gcc linker option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) documentation includes:

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified.
> Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o` searches library ‘`z`’ after file `foo.o` but
> before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in ‘`z`’, those functions may not be loaded.

It is best practice to always list libraries after your source or object files when compiling with `gcc` or `g++`. That ensures that the linker will correctly resolve all symbols. That is why moving the `-l` options to the end of the command solved your problem.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! I spent days on this. (I'll award the points as soon as StackOverflow lets me in 15 hours.) I must say that it's frustrating that "they" would make a breaking change to something that's been around for years. There are many people like me who are not experts, and a C/C++ program is just a very small part of an overall project they maintain. I'm sure there was a very good reason in someone's mind, but I wish they would think about folks that don't live in their world...

Comment: @ScottyB I agree with you: it can be quite frustrating. I haven't seen the exact reason for that specific change, though.

Comment: @ScottyB That was also mentioned in [Cannot link static library after upgrading gcc to version 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73572535/cannot-link-static-library-after-upgrading-gcc-to-version-10#comment129925413_73572535).